# div with animation above image map

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following project: https://sporedev.ro/pleiade/ (ignore the sounds, they won't autoplay in the future).

I am trying to add the sun from this codepen: https://codepen.io/Hackroro/pen/ByrKLZ

I figured out that in order for the sun to show on the page I need to add it right after `<div class="mapify-holder">`. The problem with this is that [mapify](https://github.com/etienne-martin/Mapify) adds this class dynamically.

This is the HTML code that I need to insert after the `<div class="mapify-holder">`.

```
<div class="sun">
    <div class="ray_box">
        <div class="ray ray1"></div>
        <div class="ray ray2"></div>
        <div class="ray ray3"></div>
        <div class="ray ray4"></div>
        <div class="ray ray5"></div>
        <div class="ray ray6"></div>
        <div class="ray ray7"></div>
        <div class="ray ray8"></div>
        <div class="ray ray9"></div>
        <div class="ray ray10"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the actual code of the page:

```
default:
            var htmlcode = '<img src="images/Intrare.jpg" usemap="#map" class="map full-img" width="1920px" height="1080px">';
            htmlcode += '<map name="map" id="map">';
            htmlcode += '<area shape="poly" coords="152,267,162,271,171,286,171,308,169,315,172,325,166,328,166,336,166,344,176,355,190,367,216,386,217,401,204,422,193,434,167,444,127,437,86,435,82,425,71,424,53,406,51,378,50,372,74,358,87,350,98,348,107,344,105,336,103,326,99,313,94,305,98,292,103,284,105,278,111,269,124,266,132,264" alt="" title="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="highlight"/>';   
            htmlcode += '<area shape="poly" coords="511,393,517,397,521,406,522,411,522,417,522,420,520,423,522,427,522,431,520,434,520,438,519,442,521,447,528,453,534,458,547,466,553,473,552,480,542,496,530,505,521,508,504,505,493,504,477,502,469,503,466,495,459,495,451,488,447,479,446,465,444,462,457,453,470,447,481,443,481,437,479,429,477,425,475,416,476,407,483,398,493,392" alt="" title="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"/>';     
            htmlcode += '<area shape="poly" coords="697,460,702,462,706,469,706,478,704,481,706,486,705,488,704,490,702,497,707,499,710,503,717,508,727,515,726,525,718,535,706,542,693,542,683,539,667,539,665,534,660,534,652,525,649,514,651,509,659,502,667,500,674,498,676,487,672,482,673,470,678,461,689,459" alt="" title="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"/>'; 
            htmlcode += '<area shape="poly" coords="814,500,817,505,818,514,818,520,817,527,821,532,826,535,834,540,835,547,831,552,826,559,821,561,814,561,803,559,796,558,788,555,783,554,779,550,777,543,776,536,783,533,789,530,796,527,796,521,793,514,794,507,798,501,806,500" alt="" title="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"/>'; 
            htmlcode += '<area data-group-id="group-1" shape="poly" coords="1168,676,1167,571,1171,564,1177,561,1185,559,1193,558,1204,560,1212,563,1216,567,1217,572,1218,677" onclick="zoomTo(4)" alt="" title=""/>'; 
            htmlcode += '<area data-group-id="group-1" shape="poly" coords="1257,676,1256,569,1259,565,1268,560,1278,558,1287,558,1293,559,1298,560,1304,564,1306,568,1307,677" onclick="zoomTo(4)"  alt="" title=""/>';    
            htmlcode += '<area shape="poly" coords="1037,647,1039,647,1043,647,1047,649,1049,652,1049,655,1048,659,1048,663,1046,665,1044,665,1042,668,1044,667,1050,665,1054,662,1056,661,1057,653,1059,648,1062,644,1067,643,1070,647,1071,652,1070,658,1068,661,1069,663,1073,663,1077,665,1079,669,1079,673,1080,676,1084,680,1086,683,1086,688,1085,694,1085,699,1080,704,1079,707,1078,715,1077,723,1075,735,1073,743,1073,748,1078,755,1084,763,1086,767,1088,762,1090,753,1092,744,1100,703,1099,699,1102,690,1091,687,1091,684,1093,678,1096,672,1099,666,1102,660,1108,661,1106,656,1103,649,1105,645,1108,641,1115,642,1119,645,1122,649,1120,654,1118,657,1121,659,1123,663,1127,666,1129,668,1129,675,1126,682,1123,690,1123,694,1129,694,1133,694,1137,695,1139,679,1139,671,1144,664,1144,657,1140,657,1138,655,1137,652,1138,643,1140,640,1145,638,1151,640,1152,649,1153,654,1158,657,1162,662,1165,677,1164,691,1162,716,1164,719,1159,720,1160,725,1161,737,1161,776,1161,782,1162,783,1158,785,1156,787,1148,788,1139,789,1137,783,1139,780,1146,779,1147,772,1146,762,1144,751,1141,740,1138,723,1136,712,1135,701,1124,701,1122,704,1124,708,1124,716,1124,723,1124,732,1125,742,1125,751,1123,772,1120,777,1118,780,1117,784,1113,783,1113,781,1112,777,1112,770,1116,755,1115,745,1112,724,1110,719,1108,726,1103,739,1100,761,1097,775,1091,777,1088,781,1084,784,1080,784,1080,780,1079,780,1074,782,1067,782,1063,779,1064,767,1064,758,1060,750,1056,763,1050,774,1056,784,1063,785,1065,790,1054,789,1041,789,1035,781,1033,767,1036,764,1035,756,1032,740,1030,720,1022,717,1023,707,1018,697,1017,694,1025,671,1027,670,1031,664,1033,661,1032,654,1033,649" href="test.html"  alt="" title=""/>';
            htmlcode += '<area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="1360,885,1362,800,1473,800,1471,887" />';  
            htmlcode += '<area alt="Lobby" title="" href="lobby.html" shape="poly" coords="1473,800,1472,886,1548,886,1547,800" />';
            htmlcode += '<area alt="Hol" title="" href="hol.html" shape="poly" coords="1358,887,1549,887,1550,953,1359,953" />';
            htmlcode += '<area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="1357,954,1423,953,1423,1021,1354,1022" />';
            htmlcode += '</map>';
            imgContainer.innerHTML = htmlcode
            break    
        }
```

The `<image>` and the `<area>`s are inside a [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)conditional because I need different image maps with different areas for different resolutions.

I tried adding a higher `z-index` for the "sun" `div` but it won't display on top of the image.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: so when does mapify add the class element ? can you have a listener that would wait for the mapify to populate that element and then call it after wards by detecting it?

Comment: Frankly JS is not my area of expertise. But I guess that if I'd do that the modification would apply to all the pages where mapify is loaded. And I only want the sun to load on that particular page. It should be in some kind of conditional.

Comment: Hmm something like this: https://imgur.com/a/o1PIr ?

Comment: Exactly. I'll place the sun in the upper part of the page but that's the idea, yes.

Comment: You can set: `z-index: 2` to the `.sun` class.

Comment: I moved the .sun div below the .background-container and applied z-index: 2 and it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move the sun div below the actual code

```
<div class="background-container">..</div>
<div class="sun">..</div>
```

Comment: Added z-index: 2 and it now works. Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome :) have a nice day

Comment: Unfortunately adding the z-index prevents the areas from being clickable. Any workarounds?

Comment: What do you mean by "apply javascript to it"? Can you please provide an example?

Comment: I did't mean to add some special javascript. I mean that it can be then able to cilck or you can just add href="#"

Comment: I'm using area maps, can't add #. It's not about the link, it's about not being able to hover on the areas because of the z-index. :)

Comment: what you want to do with .sun div when click on it

Comment: Nothing with .sun div but the rays from the sun prevent clicking on any of the clickable items when the ray moves above them. Check here: https://sporedev.ro/pleiade/index.html and wait for a ray to get over a clickable item (the ones that highlight).

Comment: set `.sun z-index:1;` and `ray_box z-index:-1;` It will work

tell me if it work

Comment: @SporeDev are you still there

Comment: Sorry for that, was working on another page. Applied what you said but it still won't let me click when the ray is above the clickable areas. :(

Comment: using area maps?

Comment: I don't understand from the image if you can click the items under the ray. You can see the items but can you also click them when the ray is above them? Like putting your mouse over the ray when it's above the area. It should highlight and let you click.

Comment: Sorry Bro I can't. ask experienced person

Comment: I got the answer on .sun class add
`z-index: 1; pointer-events:none;`
but then you can not able to click sun image

Comment: Thank you! That was the solution. But I didn't placed the pointer-events in the .sun class. I place it in the .ray class. When I placed it in the .sun the sun disappeared. Looked up pointer-events and figured that it should be added on the ray and hoped for the best. Seems like it worked! Thank you for your effort, you're a life saver. :)